# Can a shugenja start with mastery level 2 spells from their affinity?

Tags: character-creation, l5r-4e

I am aware that when a shugenja attains a new school rank they can choose spells of any mastery level they're allowed to cast, but I couldn't find anything in the rules stating one way or another whether a shugenja starts with all master level 1 spells, or if they can choose master level 2 spells for their affinity element.

There is an example on page 163 of a rank 1 shugenja casting a level 2 spell:

> EXAMPLE: Lucas’s character Isawa Butaro is casting Fires from Within, a Mastery Level 2 spell. Butaro is a Rank 1 Isawa Shugenja, and has Fire 3. He rolls 4k3 (4 = Fire 3 + Rank 1, keeping Fire) against TN 15 (5 + ML 2 x 5). He rolls a 2, 4, 7, and 8, keeping the 4, 7, and 8 for a total of 19. The spell has been cast successfully.

However, I don't find this entirely conclusive because it's possible the shugenja found/gained the scroll for Fires from Within after character creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first thing, this example came from Character Creation chapter, no reason to support the idea Butaro got the spell after creation.

Same for Soshi Toshiken (shugenja rank 1) on the next page, his mastery rank for Air is 2. So he can choose Air spell rank 2 at creation.

If you create a shugenja in L5RCM, you can choose spell rank 2 at creation.

The rule is badly written, you can choose spells you can cast, and your school say "Choose this number of spells". No other limit writed here.

This [post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38335/what-spells-can-a-shugenja-cast) might interest you